# Question about flight change

Tags: air-travel, expedia

So our nonstop flight from Tokyo back to LAX was moved up from 12:15AM to 10:55PM in a few months. If I call Expedia and tell them that this ruins our last night, that we just got married, etc....What are the chances I can get them to change it to a flight the next day nonstop? Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean it was moved up by an hour and 20 minutes or am I misunderstanding? Also, which airline?

Comment: It was moved up an hour and 20 min. The airline is united operated by ana

Comment: You could always call and ask...?